# Why is my file found in my local environment, but 404s on my cpanel server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

How come this work on my local environment, but 404s on my production server running cpanel:

```
$adminDir = get_bloginfo('template_directory');  
$adminDir = $adminDir."/lib/admin/";
$preview_file = $adminDir.'functions/live_preview.php';
wp_register_script( 'admin', $adminDir."js/admin.js", false, '1.0' ); //register script

$wp_paths = array( 'template_url' => $adminDir.'functions/live_preview.php');
wp_localize_script( 'admin', 'object_name', $wp_paths );
wp_enqueue_script("admin");
```

Im not sure what other information to provide, locally Im running ubuntu and apache, , I know my production environment is running some flavor of linux with apache. I have some JS sending an ajax request to the page in question with:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: object_name.template_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: data },
        success: function(result) {
            kjd_reload_styles();
        }
    });
```

I get no error on my local environment, but my ajax response results in a 404 in production. Why is that?

BUMP - So the file in question is:

```
http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/functions/live_preview.php
```

trying to hit that fails into a 404. But if you go to it's parent directory:

```
http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/functions
```

You can see the listing of files (incidentally, all of which 404). Whats up with that?

Here is my .htaccess file, it looks like the standard wordpress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Added error logs:

I went through my cpanel error logs and here is what I found. There are two types of logs, one which shows the last 300 logs, and then there is a more in depth logs.
The basic logs only show this (in fact, this error showed up today after my ajax cal action)

```
[Sat Apr 19 18:30:43 2014] [error] [client 76.100.35.2] SoftException in Application.cpp:629: Directory "/home/kylejenn/public_html/sandbox/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib" is writeable by group, referer: http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=kjd_header_settings

un Apr 20 15:31:49 2014] [error] [client 173.71.202.111] SoftException in Application.cpp:629: Directory "/home/kylejenn/public_html/sandbox/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib" is writeable by group, referer: http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=kjd_body_settings


**The in depth error logs show:**
[18-Apr-2014 15:15:36 UTC] WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_doing_cron' LIMIT 1 made by _get_cron_lock


[19-Apr-2014 20:04:48 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'z6p9z9mlt_posts.post_type' in 'where clause' for query SELECT z6p9z9mlt_comments.* FROM z6p9z9mlt_comments  WHERE comment_post_ID = '206' AND comment_approved = '1' AND z6p9z9mlt_posts.post_type NOT IN('project', 'task_list', 'task', 'milestone', 'message')  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 10 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
```

Comment: What does `object_name.template_url` return local and online?

Comment: in production the file is not found at all, I cant even pull the file up in my browser. But I pull the file up in my browser in my local environment

Comment: You may need to include your .htaccess. There may be some rewrites that are making your files into 404s.

Comment: Set permalinks to "Default" and try then.

Comment: @MichalS, I just changed them to default and it still didn't work but this time my console gave me a 500 error. Attempting to reach those files through the browser takes me to the front page. That said, the permalinks on my local environment werent set to default and Im not having that problem there.

Comment: log to cPanel, go to error log, if Mu (answer below) was on right path, there will be error for this. If you have something mess up in .htacces it will be sign in log also. Third option, exceeding resources (php) will not leave any note in this log. Let us know.

Comment: @rugbert Check for the edits in my answer.

Comment: @rugbert Can you post the log data generated when you hit the url?

Comment: What does printing this variable give the result on server $adminDir.'functions/live_preview.php'?, the same path you mentioned below?

Answer (score 1):

Since Wordpress 2.6, function get_bloginfo('template_directory') returns an URI, but you probably need a local path. Try to use the function get_theme_root() instead. In any case, if you want to check ajax comunication between your computer and the server, I suggest you to use a network protocol analyzer. I prefer Wireshark (it's avaible also for linux) , but you can choose another one.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a .htaccess file into `http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/functions/` with the following contents only

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Also, wordpress works perfectly fine without the `RewriteBase /` declaration :

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also noticed the following problems (maybe related ... maybe not )

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:53
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

Perhaps the waterfall test here may also be of some assistance regarding optimization.
**[Web Page Test](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140414%5fYR%5f9R5/)**

Lastly, when browsing to the page, I noticed that google maps was taking a VERY long time to load -- double check to ensure that it is loading in the correct order (generally last), and that it is being called using the current API's properly. -- aside from that... sometimes google is just slow, but mostly it is due to some script issues -- where the map will still render, but other things didn't setup properly so the chain-load of scripts fails somewhere. This could also cause 404's that get especially difficult to troubleshoot in environments like WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a user issue - most probably, all the files in that folder on your server have a user other than `www-data`; hence `apache` can't access those files and serve them to you.

Can you check for the same, and try changing the `username` and `group` to `www-data` using

```
cd wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/
sudo chown -r www-data:www-data functions
```

---

***EDIT 1***

I checked for some other `PHP` files on your url, all of them are giving 404. Example:

- http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/shortcode_window.php
- http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/init.php
- http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/kjd_fields.php
- http://sandbox.kylejenningsdesign.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/partials/image_slider_wrapper.php

It seems to me none of your php files are working. Hence it is a misconfiguration issue with PHP in general and not some specific problem with files in that folder.

Can you check if your php.ini settings (if accessible) are working alright? Also, if you connect to any database in your code, is the database itself accessible?

Go through the `apache` logs, and post the relevant parts of it so that we can further debug the situation.

Also, don't forget to restart `apache` everytime you make any configuration changes.

Comment: I thought I replied to this yesterday, guess it was only drafted - I checked the ownership on my local evnironment and they are indeed www-data. I cant see what they are on my production environment, but my FTP client displays a series of numbers. Not sure which user those represent . Just to be sure however, I change the file permissions to 755 so any use should be able to read and execute those files. Still nothing. Ill post my .htaccess in my original post

Comment: @rugbert Is that user same for all files? As in, in your FTP client, can you see one user for one set of files, and another for another set of files? Also, did you restart apache after file changes?

Comment: @rugbert Your `.htaccess` looks all right, I don't think that is the issue. None of your PHP files work, check edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your functions.php,

```
      /*
 * Allows access to Ajaxurl from Front end
 */
if (!function_exists('add_ajaxurl_to_front')) {
    function add_ajaxurl_to_front() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            //]]>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_ajaxurl_to_front', 1);
```

Then change the url source as "url:ajaxurl". And then try. This will work

Answer (score 0):

**Set below folder's permission to 0755** and then try...

```
/wp-content/themes/bootstrappedWP/lib/admin/functions
```